# Is there a difference between the original repo and forked repo, in respect to PRs?

Tags: fork, pull-request

What is the best way to start working on a customer's project - should I ask the customer to create and empty project and fork it, or he could fork mine?

I have a customer which requires to have a repository with some project I'm on, on his GitHub account.

What's the best way to handle the origin and forked repository? Here are the alternatives, as I see them:

- I create the private repository on my GitHub account for some initial work (in which the customer isn't really interested to review).
- I add the customer as collaborator.
- When the initial work is ready, the customer forks my repo.
- From this point, further updates into his repo will be done as pull requests from my repo to his, which he will be reviewing.

Or should I follow the traditional model:

- I ask the customer to create an empty repo on his account and add me as collaborator
- I fork the repo, do the commits and issue PRs to him

I'd prefer the first approach, will that work? Are there any downsides of it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the first approach would work, but it seems a bit awkward.

> I create the private repository on my GitHub account for some initial work (in which the customer isn't really interested to review).

This seems to be the reason you want to go with the first approach. Getting initial work merged could be a pain if you need to wait for reviews.

A possible solution to this would be to go with the traditional approach and have your pull requests auto-merged. One option to achieve this is a GitHub Actions workflow using the following Action.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/merge-pull-requests

After the initial work is done the workflow could be removed/disabled.

Comment: However, the automerge approach considers that the initial empty repo is created by the customer, right? Thanks!

Comment: @SergeiP Yes, the customer would setup the empty repo and add the workflow to auto-merge PRs. Then you can fork it and send PRs.